# Stuck in ELSE part of CASE used in where condition

Tags: sql, outsystems

I'm writing a SQL query where I want to use CASE statement in WHERE Clause.

My logic goes like below:

- If `MemberStatusId = 1`, then `Collaborator.Unavailability = @NullDate`
- If `MemberStatusId = 2`, then `Collaborator.Unavailability = @LastDate`
- Else `Collaborator.Unavailability > @NullDate` AND then `Collaborator.Unavailability < @LastDate`.

First attempt:

```
{Collaborator}.[UnavailabilityEndDate] = 
    CASE 
        WHEN @MemberStatusId = 1 THEN @NullDate
        WHEN @MemberStatusId = 2 THEN @LastDate
        ELSE @NullDate AND @LastDate 
    END;
```

I don't know what to write in ELSE part to make check the `UnavailabilityEndDate` between `NullDate` and `LastDate`.

Second attempt - but this results in an error:

```
CASE 
    WHEN @MemberStatusId = 1 THEN {Collaborator}. [UnavailabilityEndDate] = @NullDate 
    WHEN @MemberStatusId = 2 THEN {Collaborator}.[UnavailabilityEndDate] = @LastDate 
    ELSE {Collaborator}. [UnavailabilityEndDate] > @NullDate AND [Collaborator].[UnavailabilityEndDate] < @LastDate
```

Error:

[image]

NOTE: I tried to code sample or <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> but it didn't work for me to format or style the code in the comment box.

Comment: (Formatting tip) When editing, write your code with proper indentation. Highlight and click `{}`.

Comment: `CASE` is an **expression** that can return a single, scalar, atomic value to the caller - it **cannot** return entire code fragments and stuff like that ...

Comment: @jarlh I tried but it was only adding a tab for me and not formatting it like it needed to. I'm really sorry

Comment: You can also add three back-ticks on the row before the code block, and three back-ticks on the row after the code-block.

Answer (score 4):

`CASE` in a `WHERE` clause makes little sense. With `CASE` you can check a condition in order to generate a value. Why generate that value in order to check it again in the `WHERE` clause? Just check the *condition* in the `WHERE` clause right away instead. In your case:

```
WHERE (MemberStatusId = 1 AND Collaborator.Unavailability = @NullDate)
   OR (MemberStatusId = 2 AND Collaborator.Unavailability = @LastDate)
   OR (MemberStatusId NOT IN (1,2) AND Collaborator.Unavailability > @NullDate
                                   AND Collaborator.Unavailability < @LastDate)
```

Comment: I'm trying to filter out data from the dropdown based on the value from dropdown, if the dropdown selected value is 0, then return all values, if 1 return actif, else inactif. With the above answer, it would give me everything which would be valid for `MemberStatusId = 0`, not for others

Comment: Active? Inactive? These are new vocabulary here. I've shown you how to write a `WHERE` clause for the conditions in your request. If you have other conditions, then adjust the clause with what you have learned from my answer. Use parentheses to combine `AND` and `OR`.